# Divergence of definite integral

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Prove that $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{e^{-st}}{t^2}\,dt$ diverges.

My progress: I have encountered several problems so far where integral was improper and given integration was possible to express explicitly. However, my main struggles in this problem are $1)$ I can not even find to which function this is equivalent and $2)$ How can I use limit concept to prove the divergence? Any help or ideas would be strongly welcomed!

Comment: Can you say something about the behaviour of the function near $t=0$?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no ideas of what happens when $t$ is near zero. It would be welcomed if you could provide explicit solution to this problem so that I could understand fully.

Comment: Note that $e^{-st} \sim 1$ near $t=0$, whence the integrand behaves like $1/t^2$ near the origin.

Comment: Could you please explicitly conclude why given integral is divergent? I am really sorry but I struggle to prove the divergence of definite integrals wherein given function can not be integrated.

Comment: Can someone provide any detailed solution to this problem? I really need help to solve this problem.

Comment: You have provided no hint of where your difficulty lies. Where are you having trouble with this? People have been giving good guidance, but they are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: I do not what are the techniques to solve it. I have informed about my progress and what I knew in this domain. I need help from anyone who could detailedly explain the steps so that in one comment or solution, I and others can understand it easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $s\geq0$, $st\leq s$ for $0<t<1$ and so, $\frac{e^{-st}}{t^2}\geq \frac{e^{-s}}{t^2}$. From $\int^1_0\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt=\infty$ you get that the integral of interest  diverges to infinity. A similar argument works if $s<0$.

Comment: Finally, thank you very much for very detailed solution!